# Rails render another model's xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model in rails with the following method:

```
  def current_project
    if(self.active_project != nil)
      @project = Project.find(self.active_project)
    end
  end
```

Note:  active_project is an integer field on User which corresponds to the id of the project they are working on.

When I get the xml version of the User model, the project only renders the id, not all the other fields on that model - title, description, etc.

What do I need to do get the xml version of User to render all of the properties of the Project?

Comment: There seems to be no difference between `active_project` and `current_project`, so I don't think you need this method. Aside from that I don't have a solution for your problem. I tried it in one of my projects and when I do the equivalent of `self.active_project.to_xml`, it works fine.

Comment: sorry, active_project is just an id, the id of the project the person is working on

Comment: Ah, I misread your question. You mean that when you call `user_instance.to_xml` you only get the id of the project, instead of all the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the use of having such a `current_project` method. Maybe you can give some more information? Right now it seems that a simple

```
format.xml { render :xml => @user.to_xml(:include => :active_project) }
```

should work for your purpose. Am I missing something?

**Edit: After reading the comments to the original thread**

```
format.xml { render :xml => @user.to_xml(:methods => :current_project) }
```

will do the job.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the way to go.

Comment: The second line is actually what I am doing that's causing it to render just the id.

Comment: Figured it out, had to set up a proper belongs_to/has_many relationship btwn Users and Projects, then the include in your first line of code worked.  Thanks!!